# How nodejs app to request to my another https server?

Tags: node.js, https, request

Below is nodejs app to request to my another https server

```
var https = require('https');

jsonObject = JSON.stringify({"arg1":"4","arg2":"True"});

// prepare the header
var postheaders = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Length' : Buffer.byteLength(jsonObject, 'utf8')
};

// the post options
var optionspost = {
    host : 'https://www.example.com/',
    path : '/my/path/?arg1=4&arg2=True',
    method : 'POST',
    headers : postheaders
};

var reqPost = https.request(optionspost, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.info('POST result:\n');
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.info('\n\nPOST completed');
    });
});

reqPost.write(jsonObject);
reqPost.end();
reqPost.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

I always got below errors anybody can say where i went wrong

{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://www.example.com/]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'https://www.example.com/' }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// the post options
var optionspost = {
    host : 'www.example.com',
    path : '/my/path/?arg1=4&arg2=True',
    method : 'POST',
    headers : postheader
}
```

The host attribute needs to be a fully qualified domain name. Remove the https:// and the trailing slash and it should work.